# Can I use UDN as a unique id for chromecast

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromecast, google-cast

I noticed that as part of the device discovery exchange, device-desc.xml file contains a UDN value.
Can I use this as a unique id for that chromecast device?

Comment: Why do you need a unique id for the chromecast device?

Comment: To uniquely identify the chromecast device :) Joke aside, When my sender app give my cdn url to the receiver app to play a video, i want to see collect some metrics on that usage and i want to tie that metrics to that device. If there is a better way to do it without unique id, I would be glad to use it.

Comment: Did you figure out how to retrieve the UDN programmatically? I can't get past XHR restrictions if I try to retrieve device-desc.xml from JS...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the UDN as a unique identifier for a particular Chromecast.

UDN typically means "unique device name" and the format looks like a UUID which was made so that you can uniquely identify things.

As for your other question about how to collect metrics, it depends on what you want to collect and why.

If, for example, you wanted to figure out what the social usage of your app was (assuming that you had some multi-participant logic) you could track usage by device and see if certain devices are hubs of social activity and see usage patterns. This might help you figure out what sorts of features you need and help you determine if you have repeat users or if you have repeat locations meaning that you may want to persist state in different places.

However, I would suppose that the most value can be gained by attaching behaviors to users. It may be better to track application sessions and attach data to a session which would indicate how users interacted with your app and with each other. You can define a "session" in multiple ways. It could be the duration of a user's "joining" of a receiver app or the life of the receiver app itself. Probably a bit of both would be best.